# New switch widget

Tags: flutter

does anyone know why in my app I cant get the same switched that this flutter web mentions?

[Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html)

Here's what I see in my app
[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you don't use Material 3 theming in your app.
You'd need to add this:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true), // or in your custom ThemeData
  ...
)
```